pagestyle{fancy}: long section title overlap with content
Long section's title overlap with section content as shown on attached picture. Thank you for any help.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}  %%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning, babel}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} %
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white, 
%fill opacity=0.5,
inner sep=15pt]{%
  \huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\strut\thechapter\autodot~%
  \parbox[t]{14cm}{\raggedright#1\strut}};

\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right side of the book

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable headers and footers again

\chapter*{Préambule}
\section{Equivalences entre expressions régulières, automates finis, et grammaires régulières, Equivalences entre expressions régulières, automates finis, et grammaires régulières}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat. Aenean ante nibh, feugiat ut lorem sed, blandit laoreet ipsum. Aliquam convallis nisl eu velit dictum, eget venenatis libero egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ac lorem elementum, fermentum justo sit amet, rhoncus sapien. Aenean sit amet diam nulla. Aenean eros nulla, bibendum nec consectetur cursus, mollis vel lectus. Mauris orci magna, vulputate eu bibendum facilisis, porttitor feugiat dui. Nulla interdum, sapien ut pharetra auctor, ante lorem elementum arcu, sit amet iaculis purus metus ut lorem. Duis sodales dui eu lacus tempor feugiat.

Nam scelerisque nunc quis metus elementum eleifend. Sed et malesuada leo, non lacinia nibh. Proin ac ligula sed lectus pharetra venenatis. Proin eu mi a orci aliquet pulvinar. Nulla tempor ut orci quis rhoncus. In euismod sapien mauris, et scelerisque urna luctus et. Aenean egestas nibh vel ex eleifend, congue ultricies diam tincidunt. Vivamus placerat sapien finibus, laoreet mauris ut, ultrices leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas et gravida elit. Donec eu commodo neque.

Vestibulum ut libero sed dui tincidunt lacinia. Maecenas ultrices tempor risus a tristique. Praesent ante purus, dapibus et tristique in, suscipit eu mi. Suspendisse vel luctus nisl, aliquam rutrum nisl. Proin pretium dolor eget orci posuere congue. Etiam id ipsum at lacus varius consectetur eu nec nulla. Aliquam tortor ex, aliquam at libero nec, interdum sodales ante. Morbi facilisis ex est, id malesuada dui faucibus sed. Praesent ac lorem porttitor, ornare turpis quis, ultrices lectus.

Curabitur suscipit ultrices est in luctus. Duis feugiat at tellus id dignissim. Sed ultrices luctus ornare. Sed risus nibh, ultrices a libero ac, tincidunt efficitur ligula. Mauris ac tristique velit. Fusce eget sem non dui ullamcorper commodo a non magna. Phasellus massa erat, mollis ac sollicitudin sit amet, bibendum ac nibh. Nunc eu elementum lectus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus sollicitudin mi et ex vehicula interdum. Sed non nulla at turpis rhoncus elementum. Integer laoreet nibh pharetra elit auctor auctor. Fusce sit amet malesuada sem. Nam congue gravida posuere. Nulla rhoncus tortor ut eros placerat posuere. Ut tincidunt nisi tellus, a finibus elit vehicula in. Integer sit amet tortor non tellus luctus sollicitudin id at urna. Vestibulum cursus non sapien non maximus. Pellentesque ut libero eu lacus fermentum elementum. Integer at convallis metus. Praesent auctor massa eros, vitae porttitor lorem ultricies id. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat. Aenean ante nibh, feugiat ut lorem sed, blandit laoreet ipsum. Aliquam convallis nisl eu velit dictum, eget venenatis libero egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ac lorem elementum, fermentum justo sit amet, rhoncus sapien. Aenean sit amet diam nulla. Aenean eros nulla, bibendum nec consectetur cursus, mollis vel lectus. Mauris orci magna, vulputate eu bibendum facilisis, porttitor feugiat dui. Nulla interdum, sapien ut pharetra auctor, ante lorem elementum arcu, sit amet iaculis purus metus ut lorem. Duis sodales dui eu lacus tempor feugiat.

Nam scelerisque nunc quis metus elementum eleifend. Sed et malesuada leo, non lacinia nibh. Proin ac ligula sed lectus pharetra venenatis. Proin eu mi a orci aliquet pulvinar. Nulla tempor ut orci quis rhoncus. In euismod sapien mauris, et scelerisque urna luctus et. Aenean egestas nibh vel ex eleifend, congue ultricies diam tincidunt. Vivamus placerat sapien finibus, laoreet mauris ut, ultrices leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas et gravida elit. Donec eu commodo neque.

Vestibulum ut libero sed dui tincidunt lacinia. Maecenas ultrices tempor risus a tristique. Praesent ante purus, dapibus et tristique in, suscipit eu mi. Suspendisse vel luctus nisl, aliquam rutrum nisl. Proin pretium dolor eget orci posuere congue. Etiam id ipsum at lacus varius consectetur eu nec nulla. Aliquam tortor ex, aliquam at libero nec, interdum sodales ante. Morbi facilisis ex est, id malesuada dui faucibus sed. Praesent ac lorem porttitor, ornare turpis quis, ultrices lectus.

Curabitur suscipit ultrices est in luctus. Duis feugiat at tellus id dignissim. Sed ultrices luctus ornare. Sed risus nibh, ultrices a libero ac, tincidunt efficitur ligula. Mauris ac tristique velit. Fusce eget sem non dui ullamcorper commodo a non magna. Phasellus massa erat, mollis ac sollicitudin sit amet, bibendum ac nibh. Nunc eu elementum lectus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus sollicitudin mi et ex vehicula interdum. Sed non nulla at turpis rhoncus elementum. Integer laoreet nibh pharetra elit auctor auctor. Fusce sit amet malesuada sem. Nam congue gravida posuere. Nulla rhoncus tortor ut eros placerat posuere. Ut tincidunt nisi tellus, a finibus elit vehicula in. Integer sit amet tortor non tellus luctus sollicitudin id at urna. Vestibulum cursus non sapien non maximus. Pellentesque ut libero eu lacus fermentum elementum. Integer at convallis metus. Praesent auctor massa eros, vitae porttitor lorem ultricies id. 
\chapter*{Bibliographie}

\end{document}


not presumably the problem but: nesting tikzpictures isn't supported. nesting two with remember picture, overlay in both seems an odd choice. what's the intention there? more generally, what do you want to know? you are using code which places your chapter title at a fixed point regardless and makes no allowance for changes to length or size. so, if you use a long enough title, it will inevitably overlap other content. anytime you use overlay, you have to allow manually for the space content requires. there's no other way to do it.

Errors. You missed \makeatletter. You only defining makeschapterhead. How about makechapterhead (note the s). The running head can be changed (see the warning) fancy is giving you. \addtolength{\topmargin}{-46.11858pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{60pt}

@cfr  Why you say that nesting two remember picture,overlay is not supported? There is nothing like it in the manual. The remember just records the position in the aux and the overlay  is just zero width and height boxes. Not the problem with the OP, but I have similar designs to what he is looking and they working fine.  so overlay acts like scope.

@yannisl I did not say that. I said nesting tikzpictures is not supported. sometimes it seems to work, though it is almost always avoidable, but it only works by chance unless you really know what you are doing. (I said nesting with those options was an odd choice, but that is a secondary point. The primary on holds regardless of options.) if you really know what you're doing, you know it can almost always be avoided.

@yannisl you can nest scopes and use overlay as a scoped option. that's fine. and also supported behaviour.

@cfr  Thanks, I will give it a try.

@yannis your solution \addtolength{\topmargin}{-46.11858pt} \setlength{\headheight}{60pt} fixed my problem. Thank you.

@yannis maybe you could set your solution as an answer so I could accept it.

@cProg Thanks, best provide a short answer yourself.  Did you umanage to fix the rest of the errors?

Following @yannist comment:

The running head can be changed (see the warning) fancy is giving you.
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-46.11858pt} \setlength{\headheight}{60pt}

this is how I rewrite my code. I have added the line and that fixed the problem described in question:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}  %%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning, babel}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} %
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white, 
%fill opacity=0.5,
inner sep=15pt]{%
  \huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\strut\thechapter\autodot~%
  \parbox[t]{14cm}{\raggedright#1\strut}};

\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right side of the book

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable headers and footers again

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-46.11858pt} \setlength{\headheight}{60pt}

\chapter*{Préambule}
\section{Equivalences entre expressions régulières, automates finis, et grammaires régulières, Equivalences entre expressions régulières, automates finis, et grammaires régulières}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat. Aenean ante nibh, feugiat ut lorem sed, blandit laoreet ipsum. Aliquam convallis nisl eu velit dictum, eget venenatis libero egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ac lorem elementum, fermentum justo sit amet, rhoncus sapien. Aenean sit amet diam nulla. Aenean eros nulla, bibendum nec consectetur cursus, mollis vel lectus. Mauris orci magna, vulputate eu bibendum facilisis, porttitor feugiat dui. Nulla interdum, sapien ut pharetra auctor, ante lorem elementum arcu, sit amet iaculis purus metus ut lorem. Duis sodales dui eu lacus tempor feugiat.

Nam scelerisque nunc quis metus elementum eleifend. Sed et malesuada leo, non lacinia nibh. Proin ac ligula sed lectus pharetra venenatis. Proin eu mi a orci aliquet pulvinar. Nulla tempor ut orci quis rhoncus. In euismod sapien mauris, et scelerisque urna luctus et. Aenean egestas nibh vel ex eleifend, congue ultricies diam tincidunt. Vivamus placerat sapien finibus, laoreet mauris ut, ultrices leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas et gravida elit. Donec eu commodo neque.

Vestibulum ut libero sed dui tincidunt lacinia. Maecenas ultrices tempor risus a tristique. Praesent ante purus, dapibus et tristique in, suscipit eu mi. Suspendisse vel luctus nisl, aliquam rutrum nisl. Proin pretium dolor eget orci posuere congue. Etiam id ipsum at lacus varius consectetur eu nec nulla. Aliquam tortor ex, aliquam at libero nec, interdum sodales ante. Morbi facilisis ex est, id malesuada dui faucibus sed. Praesent ac lorem porttitor, ornare turpis quis, ultrices lectus.

Curabitur suscipit ultrices est in luctus. Duis feugiat at tellus id dignissim. Sed ultrices luctus ornare. Sed risus nibh, ultrices a libero ac, tincidunt efficitur ligula. Mauris ac tristique velit. Fusce eget sem non dui ullamcorper commodo a non magna. Phasellus massa erat, mollis ac sollicitudin sit amet, bibendum ac nibh. Nunc eu elementum lectus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus sollicitudin mi et ex vehicula interdum. Sed non nulla at turpis rhoncus elementum. Integer laoreet nibh pharetra elit auctor auctor. Fusce sit amet malesuada sem. Nam congue gravida posuere. Nulla rhoncus tortor ut eros placerat posuere. Ut tincidunt nisi tellus, a finibus elit vehicula in. Integer sit amet tortor non tellus luctus sollicitudin id at urna. Vestibulum cursus non sapien non maximus. Pellentesque ut libero eu lacus fermentum elementum. Integer at convallis metus. Praesent auctor massa eros, vitae porttitor lorem ultricies id. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat. Aenean ante nibh, feugiat ut lorem sed, blandit laoreet ipsum. Aliquam convallis nisl eu velit dictum, eget venenatis libero egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ac lorem elementum, fermentum justo sit amet, rhoncus sapien. Aenean sit amet diam nulla. Aenean eros nulla, bibendum nec consectetur cursus, mollis vel lectus. Mauris orci magna, vulputate eu bibendum facilisis, porttitor feugiat dui. Nulla interdum, sapien ut pharetra auctor, ante lorem elementum arcu, sit amet iaculis purus metus ut lorem. Duis sodales dui eu lacus tempor feugiat.

Nam scelerisque nunc quis metus elementum eleifend. Sed et malesuada leo, non lacinia nibh. Proin ac ligula sed lectus pharetra venenatis. Proin eu mi a orci aliquet pulvinar. Nulla tempor ut orci quis rhoncus. In euismod sapien mauris, et scelerisque urna luctus et. Aenean egestas nibh vel ex eleifend, congue ultricies diam tincidunt. Vivamus placerat sapien finibus, laoreet mauris ut, ultrices leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas et gravida elit. Donec eu commodo neque.

Vestibulum ut libero sed dui tincidunt lacinia. Maecenas ultrices tempor risus a tristique. Praesent ante purus, dapibus et tristique in, suscipit eu mi. Suspendisse vel luctus nisl, aliquam rutrum nisl. Proin pretium dolor eget orci posuere congue. Etiam id ipsum at lacus varius consectetur eu nec nulla. Aliquam tortor ex, aliquam at libero nec, interdum sodales ante. Morbi facilisis ex est, id malesuada dui faucibus sed. Praesent ac lorem porttitor, ornare turpis quis, ultrices lectus.

Curabitur suscipit ultrices est in luctus. Duis feugiat at tellus id dignissim. Sed ultrices luctus ornare. Sed risus nibh, ultrices a libero ac, tincidunt efficitur ligula. Mauris ac tristique velit. Fusce eget sem non dui ullamcorper commodo a non magna. Phasellus massa erat, mollis ac sollicitudin sit amet, bibendum ac nibh. Nunc eu elementum lectus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus sollicitudin mi et ex vehicula interdum. Sed non nulla at turpis rhoncus elementum. Integer laoreet nibh pharetra elit auctor auctor. Fusce sit amet malesuada sem. Nam congue gravida posuere. Nulla rhoncus tortor ut eros placerat posuere. Ut tincidunt nisi tellus, a finibus elit vehicula in. Integer sit amet tortor non tellus luctus sollicitudin id at urna. Vestibulum cursus non sapien non maximus. Pellentesque ut libero eu lacus fermentum elementum. Integer at convallis metus. Praesent auctor massa eros, vitae porttitor lorem ultricies id. 
\chapter*{Bibliographie}

\end{document}

